# Missing compile step?

Tags: catkin, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm learning ROS for Turtlebot3, and am getting an error message that appears to tell me that I missed a compilation or build step. Perhaps I am missing an environment variable. Here are the key steps:

```
$ catkin_create_pkg wanderbot rospy geometry_msgs sensor_msgs

$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
pitosalas@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/wanderbot/src$ ./redgreen.py 
from: can't read /var/mail/geometry_msgs.msg
./redgreen.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./redgreen.py: line 6: `cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1) #<1>'
```

And looking for the missing geometry_msgs.msg:

```
pitosalas@ubuntu:/$ ls -l /opt/ros/kinetic/share/geometry_msgs/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 23 18:39 cmake
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 23 18:39 msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  794 Sep 30  2016 package.xml
```

And inside you can see the Twist.msg:

```
ls -l /opt/ros/kinetic/share/geometry_msgs/msg/
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 119 Sep 30  2016 Accel.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  83 Sep 30  2016 AccelStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 330 Sep 30  2016 AccelWithCovariance.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124 Sep 30  2016 AccelWithCovarianceStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 235 Sep 30  2016 Inertia.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  30 Sep 30  2016 InertiaStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 367 Sep 30  2016 Point32.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  84 Sep 30  2016 Point.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  98 Sep 30  2016 PointStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 107 Sep 30  2016 Polygon.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104 Sep 30  2016 PolygonStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  96 Sep 30  2016 Pose2D.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85 Sep 30  2016 PoseArray.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 119 Sep 30  2016 Pose.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  79 Sep 30  2016 PoseStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 323 Sep 30  2016 PoseWithCovariance.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 122 Sep 30  2016 PoseWithCovarianceStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 108 Sep 30  2016 Quaternion.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 Sep 30  2016 QuaternionStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 Sep 30  2016 Transform.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 337 Sep 30  2016 TransformStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 115 Sep 30  2016 Twist.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  82 Sep 30  2016 TwistStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 326 Sep 30  2016 TwistWithCovariance.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124 Sep 30  2016 TwistWithCovarianceStamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 382 Sep 30  2016 Vector3.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 103 Sep 30  2016 Vector3Stamped.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 Sep 30  2016 Wrench.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85 Sep 30  2016 WrenchStamped.msg
pitosalas@ubuntu:/$
```

Here's the full source of red green.py:

```
#example 1
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1) #<1>
rospy.init_node('red_light_green_light')

red_light_twist = Twist() #<2>
green_light_twist = Twist()
green_light_twist.linear.x = 0.5 #<3>

driving_forward = False
light_change_time = rospy.Time.now()
rate = rospy.Rate(10)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
  if driving_forward:
    cmd_vel_pub.publish(green_light_twist) #<4>
  else:
    cmd_vel_pub.publish(red_light_twist)
  # BEGIN PART_1
  if rospy.Time.now() > light_change_time: #<5>
    driving_forward = not driving_forward
    light_change_time = rospy.Time.now() + rospy.Duration(3)
  # END PART_1
  rate.sleep() #<6>
# END ALL
```

And here's the environment (updated, moved wanderbot under src as @gvdhoorn said)

```
pitosalas@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ tree .
.
├── build
│   ├── beginner_tutorials
│   │   ├── catkin_generated
│   │   │   ├── installspace
│   │   │   │   ├── beginner_tutorialsConfig.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── beginner_tutorialsConfig-version.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── beginner_tutorials.pc
│   │   │   ├── ordered_paths.cmake
│   │   │   ├── package.cmake
│   │   │   ├── pkg.develspace.context.pc.py
│   │   │   ├── pkg.installspace.context.pc.py
│   │   │   └── stamps
│   │   │       └── beginner_tutorials
│   │   │           ├── package.xml.stamp
│   │   │           └── pkg.pc.em.stamp
│   │   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   │   ├── roscpp_generate_messages_cpp.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── roscpp_generate_messages_eus.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── roscpp_generate_messages_lisp.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── roscpp_generate_messages_py.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── std_msgs_generate_messages_eus.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   ├── std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   │   └── std_msgs_generate_messages_py.dir
│   │   │       ├── build.make
│   │   │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │       └── progress.make
│   │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   │   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   │   └── Makefile
│   ├── catkin
│   │   └── catkin_generated
│   │       └── version
│   │           └── package.cmake
│   ├── catkin_generated
│   │   ├── env_cached.sh
│   │   ├── generate_cached_setup.py
│   │   ├── installspace
│   │   │   ├── env.sh
│   │   │   ├── setup.bash
│   │   │   ├── setup.sh
│   │   │   ├── _setup_util.py
│   │   │   └── setup.zsh
│   │   ├── order_packages.cmake
│   │   ├── order_packages.py
│   │   ├── setup_cached.sh
│   │   └── stamps
│   │       └── Project
│   │           ├── interrogate_setup_dot_py.py.stamp
│   │           ├── order_packages.cmake.em.stamp
│   │           ├── package.xml.stamp
│   │           └── _setup_util.py.stamp
│   ├── CATKIN_IGNORE
│   ├── catkin_make.cache
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.5.1
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   └── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       └── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │   ├── clean_test_results.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeError.log
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeRuleHashes.txt
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── download_extra_data.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── doxygen.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── feature_tests.bin
│   │   ├── feature_tests.c
│   │   ├── feature_tests.cxx
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   ├── run_tests.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   └── tests.dir
│   │       ├── build.make
│   │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │       └── progress.make
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   ├── gtest
│   │   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   │   ├── gtest.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   ├── gtest_main.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   └── progress.marks
│   │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   │   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   │   └── Makefile
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── test_results
│   └── wanderbot
│       ├── catkin_generated
│       │   ├── installspace
│       │   │   ├── wanderbotConfig.cmake
│       │   │   ├── wanderbotConfig-version.cmake
│       │   │   └── wanderbot.pc
│       │   ├── ordered_paths.cmake
│       │   ├── package.cmake
│       │   ├── pkg.develspace.context.pc.py
│       │   ├── pkg.installspace.context.pc.py
│       │   └── stamps
│       │       └── wanderbot
│       │           ├── package.xml.stamp
│       │           └── pkg.pc.em.stamp
│       ├── CMakeFiles
│       │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│       │   ├── geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── progress.marks
│       │   ├── sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   ├── sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs.dir
│       │   │   ├── build.make
│       │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │   │   └── progress.make
│       │   └── sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py.dir
│       │       ├── build.make
│       │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│       │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│       │       └── progress.make
│       ├── cmake_install.cmake
│       ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│       └── Makefile
├── devel
│   ├── env.sh
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── pkgconfig
│   │       ├── beginner_tutorials.pc
│   │       └── wanderbot.pc
│   ├── setup.bash
│   ├── setup.sh
│   ├── _setup_util.py
│   ├── setup.zsh
│   └── share
│       ├── beginner_tutorials
│       │   └── cmake
│       │       ├── beginner_tutorialsConfig.cmake
│       │       └── beginner_tutorialsConfig-version.cmake
│       └── wanderbot
│           └── cmake
│               ├── wanderbotConfig.cmake
│               └── wanderbotConfig-version.cmake
└── src
    ├── beginner_tutorials
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── beginner_tutorials
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   └── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
    └── wanderbot
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── package.xml
        └── src
            ├── redgreen.py
            └── rospy
```

77 directories, 227 files

I won't give all the steps to get there to save space, unless I need to to further clarify.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267445/missing-compile-step?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-26**:
Why is the `wanderbot` package outside your `src` space? That won't work (well it can, but let's not complicate things).

Put it in `catkin_ws/src`, run `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`), `source` your `devel/setup.bash` and try again.

Also, check what you have on line 6 of `redgreen.py`.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-07-26**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn... I made the suggested corrections, and updated the original question above. Then run it with `cd ~./catkin_ws/src/wanderbot/src; ./redgreen.py` and got the same error. Any other suggestion would be appreciated!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-26**:
It looks like you're not finding `geometry_msgs` in `/var/mail` (`from: can't read /var/mail/geometry_msgs.msg`). Where is it installed on your system? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and using Indigo, and it's installed at `/opt/ros/indigo/share/geometry_msgs`.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-07-26**:
@jayess, thanks, it seems to be there. Also I've updated the original question with that detail and some more. Thanks for sticking with me!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-27**:
Make sure to post the entire contents of your source. I ran the previous edit of your code and didn't get any errors. I ran the current version and got your errorl

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-07-27**:
yes. I guess I was trying to unclutter the question before I had any idea that that comment was the culprit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I found the problem: the first line of the .py file was a #comment... before the shebang line. I think thats what messed everything up!

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-27**:
If this solved your question you should mark it as correct.